# Is there any option to check if API take more than 10 second to call in PHP?

Tags: php, api, cron, php-5.6, round-robin

Actually, I am implementing a cron, where I need to call more than 50 APIs. So, I want to implement something like, if an API takes more than 10 seconds to call, I will skip that.

Actually, I am using PHP 5.6. I have tried to implement Round-Robin. I haven't got anything to check if an API takes more than 10 seconds to call.

Comment: you can set a time limit but then it will give you error time out.. or you could use sleep or set_time_limit functions ..

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ReactPHP` tools for this purpose. Here examples how to work with timers https://blog.wyrihaximus.net/2015/01/reactphp-timers/

Example:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$i = 0;
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function(React\EventLoop\Timer\Timer $timer) use (&$i, $loop) {
    if ($i == 0) {
       // send request
    } elseif($i < 10){
       // check response
    } else {
        // cancel request and cancel timer
        $loop->cancelTimer($timer);
    }
    ++$i;
});

$loop->run();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try it. :)